# How to programmatically print node from a specific author

Tags: users

I am trying to print all nodes published by a specific author on my page. Anyway knows a way to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// returns an array of all nodes from the current user. 
// From this array, create whatever page display you want:
function all_nodes_from_logged_in_user( ) {
  global $user;

  $finalAnswer = array();

  // note: it's "Safe" to build a query like this when the
  // data being embedded in the query does not come from a user:
  $query = "SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE (node.uid = ".$user->uid.")".'ORDER BY node.changed DESC';

  $ret = db_query($query);
  while ($nid = db_fetch_object($ret)) {

    $node = node_load( $nid->nid ); // load entire node so all data is available to the caller
    $finalAnswer[] = $node; // put in return array
  }

  return $finalAnswer;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the  [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module I think you can add a filter on the user name.
I don't know if you are aware of this module, but for short you have to create a view with some settings like :

- Row Style : Node (or fields but then you have to add some fields)
- Filters : User-> Name (or ID)

To finish you have to add a display, for example "Page" and then edit the path. With this you can create a menu with the View Page.

See the [documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views) for more.

If it's not a good answer, can you explain more your problem ? (D6 or D7, how do you want to display the nodes...)

(Hope my english is not too bad)

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thanks for the advice although i should have make that clear in my question (i'll edit it right now) i need to that  programmatically.
And your english seems good to me, thanks again buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this programmatically, then 
instead of using **User->name** as filter, you can have it as "argument" in the view and expose it. Now you can load the view programmatically and set the value for the exposed field(i.e username).